# Import Values from column1 from fileA.csv and export values to column1 in fileB.csv

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

So I'm still a bit new at understanding some of the cmdlets in powershell. I'm trying to get the values of columns from multiple csv files and place those values in the columns of 1 file. For Example

I have a file with the following data. We'll call it FileA.csv:

```
SomeLineOfNotes
SomeLineOfNotes2
SomeLineOfNotes3
SomeLineOfNotes4
SomeLineOfNotes5
SomeLineOfNotes6
"FruitType","VegetableType","MeatType"
```

Now I want to import the values of the fruits from FileB.csv:
Note: it will be hard to use the delimiter for "," because some values have a "*,*"

```
"FruitFav","DrinkFav", "DairyFav"
"Banana","Soda","IceCream"
"Mango","EnergyDrinks,Monster","Yogurt"
"Peach","Slurpy","Cheese"
```

Now FileA.csv should have the following contents:

```
SomeLineOfNotes
SomeLineOfNotes2
SomeLineOfNotes3
SomeLineOfNotes4
SomeLineOfNotes5
SomeLineOfNotes6
"FruitType","VegetableType","MeatType"
"Banana","",""
"Mango","",""
"Peach","",""
```

Any ideas how to do this with powershell?

I'm guessing the start would be to put both files in a hash table

```
$FileAcontents = Import-Csv $FileA -Header "FruitType","VegetableType","MeatType"
$FileBcontents = Import-Csv $FileB -Header "FruitFav","DrinkFav", "DairyFav"
```

I'm lost from here...

**UPDATE**

I'll test the answers when I get the chance. I ended up going with get-content and implementing the values based on the separation of ",". Some of my future items won't work with this those items have a "," in the value. So I think I will need to temporarily remove the top not lines in the csv file and leave it with column names at the top so I can utilize the import-csv cmdlet. At the moment my boss gave me 2 days to write up a file comparing 20 different hash tables with more than 200k rows and 10 columns in each hash table with different values and different column names, and he wants appended columns based on comparisons. So I'm in a bit of a hurry to get this done (in 2 days? is this normal?).

Comment: the format of a csv file should be consistent meaning you cannot have some lines of text at the beginning fo the file and then headers. Its okay to not have headers but the file should be consistent. The delimiter can be a semi-colon instead of a comma.

Comment: does this help ? `Import-Csv -Path $FileB -Header 'FruitType','VegetableType','MeatType' | Export-Csv $FileA -Append`

Comment: eh not really, with that code it would append the icecream value in the meattype column. Anyway you are saying I should add the lines above the column headers at the end of the script? There is no way for powershell to detect the columns on any line and fill in the values for those columns? I've been thinking about just using python and skipping powershells csv cmdlets all together. I've been at this for 10 hours and my boss wants this done tomorrow.

Comment: ok perhaps i misunderstood what you were trying to do.... the lines of text should not be anywhere in the csv file, if they are then they must be part of some column, (A.B or C)...no idea about python...if it gets the job done then go for it...anyway see my answer below...posted as an answer because the code is a bit long.

Answer (score 0):

this will import only the column items that belong to fileB into fileA.
The other column values(vegtype,meattype) will be blank.

```
import-csv  $FileB | ForEach-Object {

    New-Object psobject -Property @{

     FruitType =  $_.FruitType 
     VegetableType = ''
     MeatType = ''
    }
} | Select-Object FruitType,VegetableType,MeatType | Export-Csv $FileA -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an even simpler

```
Import-Csv $FileB -Delimiter "," |
    Select-Object FruitType, VegetableType, MeatType |
    Export-Csv $FileA -NoTypeInformation
```

would make it.

You can tweak the `-Delimiter` for `Import-Csv` if needed.

Don't forget to use `-NoTypeInformation` with `Export-Csv`.